# 404 Error in the console with React Application deployed using Docker on Cloud Run

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, http-status-code-404, google-cloud-run

I have been banging my head a against a wall all night due to this error. I have deployed a front-end React app served by NGINX to Cloud Run using Terraform.

This is my first time deploying, I am aware that I do not need to containerise my application, but I am working towards a career in DevOps, so it doesn't make sense not to.

Initially, the console displayed this error:

main.jsx:1 Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

I then modified my nginx.config file to include a Content-Type application/javascript header:

```
http {

  include mime.types;

  set_real_ip_from        0.0.0.0/0;
  real_ip_recursive       on;
  real_ip_header          X-Forward-For;
  limit_req_zone          $binary_remote_addr zone=mylimit:10m rate=10r/s;

  server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name localhost;
    root /proxy;
    limit_req zone=mylimit burst=70 nodelay;

    location / {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri /index.html;   
        }

    location ~* \.jsx$ {
            add_header Content-Type application/javascript;
       }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
  }
}

events {}
```

I redeployed, here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:21.6.0-slim AS build

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:latest

COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf


EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I then started to get the following error:

GET https://andy-as-code-portfolio-pzyukotqoq-lm.a.run.app/src/main.jsx
net::ERR_ABORTED 404 NOT FOUND

My index.html file is in the root file of the project, and it looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I do not see the issue with how I am pointing to my main.jsx file. I set the local repo up using vite.